Space Shuttle Main Engine TVC actuator torque
Curious if there are references for the Shuttle Main Engine Gimballing actuator torque and the arm distance between CG of the Shuttle and the gimballing point.

The actuator torque could be any multiple of the torque that acts on the SSME (due to gearing involved). Perhaps this is an XY problem. Could you elaborate more on what you want to know?

@AJN The question ask about a well-known topic called the "tail wags dog effect". Changing thruster direction results in two effects. One is the tail (the engine) wags the dog (the vehicle body), causing the body to change direction. The other, which is more insidious, is that the control system might wag the tail one way and then another and then another in short succession. These oscillations can excite oscillations in other dynamic structures such as flex and slosh. Unfortunately, I could not find specific references regarding the Shuttle Main Engine.

Different, but an interesting comparison, and there are several references in comments to literature about the Shuttle: What kind of forces and response times/accelerations are needed to gimbal a mid-sized nine-engine rocket's engines?

The CG location of the shuttle changed a lot, especially when the main engines were active.
